# Customise bulk products on same collection in shopify theme

Tags: shopify, liquid, liquid-layout, shopify-app

Is there an option to get customisation of one product in collection and apply the customisation to all the products that comes under the same collection?

For Example:

If we customised the product such as added a link, sorted sections or blocks, inserted a text section, etc... for the product "XXXX" that comes under category "Police",  can we apply the customisation to all the products that falls under same "Police" category?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, you want a section that will be global ( the same ) for each product.

Well that's what sections exactly do at the moment if you include them in your page.

If you add a `{% section 'product-template' %}` and create all the necessary options they will be applied to each product that use the product template.

Comment: Yes, product template applies to all product.  I need a <template> for each collections. Products in "Watch" collections should have unique template tailored to the informations regarding watches, Products in "Clothes" should have unique template tailored to the informations regarding clothes, etc.. Hope you understand!

Comment: @SenthilVel The most easy way is a private app that allows you to choose which template to use based on products' attributes e.g. collection

Comment: @TienDo Thanks for your response.  We can use the template based on collection.  Can we customise the template ( same applies to whole products ) as we do when customize the page like adding pages, menu, tag list, etc..

Answer (score 1):

> In product-templet file you can check for collection Id/name and then
>   update product UI as you wish.

```
<div id="productId" class="{{product.id}}" style="display:hidden" >

 {% if collection.name == “Police” %}

  <div class="product-detail" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
   {% Here Your Customized UI to Show Products of Collection %}
      <div class="product-detail__title-and-price">
        <h1 class="product-title" itemprop="name">{{ product.title }}</h1>

        <div class="price-area emphasised">
          {% if variant.compare_at_price > variant.price %}
          <span class="was-price theme-money">{{ variant.compare_at_price | money }}</span>
          {% endif %}
          <span class="price theme-money">{{ variant.price | money }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

{% endif %}

 <div class="product-detail" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Product">
{%Your Customized UI to Show Products of Collection %}
 </div>

</div>
```

Comment: At end of the liquid template-page you can write <script>Javascript Code </script> to do anything with your Page. If you want to use External Javascript Files add them in asset folder and use {{ 'jquery-3.1.1.min.js' | asset_url | script_tag }} to link  in your page.